# Liven up the seders with photos?

Tags: children-parenting, passover-seder-hagada, pictures

Has anyone tried making the seders more attractive to kids by use of photos?  If so, what did you try and how did it work?

Update:
I have found photos of: breaking a matza, locusts, a seder plate, ancient Egyptians, various foods, Miriam's mother putting Moshe in a basket, etc.  I was thinking of numbering them and handing out copies.  The task for the kids would be to find a picture that is relevant to the part of the haggada we are reading.

What do you think of this approach?  Any other ideas on how the pictures might be used at the seder?

Comment: What kinds of photos are you thinking of? I know there are child-aimed picture haggadot available.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27160/472, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15278/472.